# Different cv-qualifiers with structured bindings

Tags: c++, c++17

The [structured binding declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations#Structured_binding_declaration) in C++17 allows for several different options, such as:

```
std::tuple<int, int> foo();

auto  [a, b] = foo(); // a and b are: int
const auto  [a, b] = foo(); // a and b are: int const
const auto& [a, b] = foo(); // a and b are: int const&
```

Is there any way to give `a` and `b` different cv-qualifiers? For example the type of `a` as `int` and `b` as `int const`?

Comment: Depending on which case is more desired, you could consider defining the tuple returned with different cv-qualifiers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No - this is covered in the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf)'s Q&A:

> > **Should the syntax be extended to allow const/&-qualifying individual names’ types?**
>
> ```
> auto [& x, const y, const& z] = f(); // NOT proposed
> ```
>
> We think the answer should be no. This is a simple feature to store a value and bind names to its components,
>   not to declare multiple variables. Allowing such qualification would be feature creep, extending the feature to
>   be something different, namely a way to declare multiple variables.
>   If we do want to declare multiple variables, we already have a way to spell it:
>
> ```
> auto val = f(); // or auto&&
> T1& x = get<0>(val);
> T2 const y = get<1>(val);
> T3 const& z = get<2>(val);
> ```

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately, `val` is still in scope then.

Comment: This is hardly equivalent. For example, range base for loops would be quite painful to watch with the `get<>()` approach.

Answer (score 8):

It's not allowed, but there seems to be some misunderstanding of how structured binding works. The following is how your snippet actually works:

```
std::tuple<int, int> foo();

auto  [a, b] = foo(); // `a` and `b` are `int`
auto& [a, b] = foo(); // error: cannot bind a non-const lvalue-ref to an rvalue.
const auto  [a, b] = foo(); // `a` and `b` are: `int const`
const auto& [a, b] = foo(); // `a` and `b` are: `int const`! (NOT `int const&`)
                            // lifetime extension of `foo()` via `const&`.
```

Based on the examples you gave, it seems to be that the mistake is in thinking that the `auto` in `auto [a, b]` **distributes** across the variables. It does not. The `auto` there is actually the type of the initializer. In C++, this is roughly encoded like this:

```
auto temp = foo();  // `auto` is for the initializer!
// These aren't actually references, but close.
auto&& a = std::get<0>(temp);
auto&& b = std::get<1>(temp);
```

This is contrary to something like:

```
auto&& temp = foo();  // save `temp` like range-based `for` does!
// if `auto` in `auto [a, b]` were distributive.
auto a = std::get<0>(temp);
auto b = std::get<1>(temp);
```